# How do i find all the tables with descriptions on SQL developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently using

SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables

to find all tables in my database, but so far I cannot find the description column for each table. Does this even exist?

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 0):

in description what you are looking for?

below is there. You just need to put specific table name here.

```
desc table_name;
```

or you can query on user_segments or dba_segments.
But if you are looking for something else, please elaborate.

Comment: So for my system i have tables information about people like one might be for income info and another might be for contact info, in my code in the question i can get all tables, but i would also like to have their description given to me in the query as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking the list of columns per table. Below query will be useful.

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns;
```

This table contains all the necessary information like Data Type, Length, Owner, Nullable etc.